# Oracle: Error in converting DateTime to Epoch

Tags: sql, oracle

While trying to convert datetime to epoch, I am getting an error: **ORA-01810: format code appears twice**

*QracleSQL query:*

```
select (trunc(TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-08T19:09:17Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ssXXX')) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) * 24 * 60 * 60 from dual;
```

Comment: It really appears twice: `mm` is the same as `MM`

Comment: I got that. But thats the pattern of the datetime I am passing in right. So how do i fix this? I tried couple of thing by changing from mm to mi.. Nothing seems working

Comment: Use HH24 (time is 19:09:17), and MI for minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

- `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` instead of `TO_TIMESTAMP`
- the format model `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD` rather than incorrectly using `MM` twice, `HH24` instead of `HH`, `.FF` instead of `XXX`, and `TZD` instead of hardcoding `"Z"`.
- Make sure you always convert your timestamp to UTC time zone (yours is already but others may not be)
- Don't `TRUNC`ate the timestamp to a `DATE` at midnight or you will lose the time component.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(
         (
           TRUNC(timestamp_value AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'MI')
           - DATE '1970-01-01'
         ) * 86400
         + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM timestamp_value AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
       ) AS epoch_time
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2022-05-08T19:09:17Z',
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD'
         ) AS timestamp_value
  FROM   DUAL
);
```

Which outputs:

> | EPOCH_TIME |
> | --- |
> | 1652033357 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c61c2f5e7893f6f6049e1bf119c7118b)*

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

TEST DATA

```
create table sample_inputs (ts_string) as
  select '2022-05-08T16:49:34Z'     from dual union all
  select '2022-04-15T04:20:13.525Z' from dual
;
```

QUERY AND OUTPUT

```
with
  prep (ts_string, ts) as (
    select ts_string,
           to_timestamp(ts_string, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff"Z"')
    from   sample_inputs
  )
select ts_string,
       round((trunc(ts, 'mi') - date '1970-01-01') * 24 * 3600)
         + extract(second from ts)
       as epoch
from   prep;

TS_STRING                        EPOCH
-------------------------- -----------
2022-05-08T16:49:34Z        1652028574
2022-04-15T04:20:13.525Z    1649996413.525
```

NOTES

In your attempt there are several mistakes. The Oracle fractional-seconds element is `ff`, not `xxx`. You are missing the placeholder for the hard-coded Z at the end (you have "T" in your mask, which is correct, but you are missing the similar "Z"). `HH` is insufficient - it must be either `HH24` or `HH` followed by `AM` (or equivalently `PM`) at the end. In your example, it is obviously `HH24`. And `MM` and `mm` mean the same thing in Oracle - this is not Unix. The element for minutes is `mi` or equivalently `MI`.

The query I wrote preserves fractional seconds in the epoch. Another question earlier today (perhaps yours too, under another user name) was closed as being a "duplicate" - but the claimed "duplicate" has absolutely nothing about preserving fractional seconds, when the input is an Oracle timestamp vs an Oracle date (which always does have a time component, but only in whole seconds).

Comment: Your last paragraph is (now) incorrect as the duplicate has been fixed on that other question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72010122/1509264) using `EXTRACT` in the (updated) linked duplicate will preserve fractional seconds.